# PHP sql table onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php script building a table. I need from the php to define a onclick event for each row  forwarding to a function.
currently not successful to call the function.

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr onclick="myFunction(this)" >

        <td>".$i."</td>
        <td>".$row["dest"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["tool"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["air_port"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["ctry_cd2"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["geo"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["carrier_td"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["required_dd"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["carrier_dd"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["TPT"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["sqf"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Weight_kg"]."</td>
        </tr>";
        $i++;
    }

    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
} 

echo $selected_sqf; 
echo $selected_weight;



?>
<script>

function myFunction(x) {
echo 12;
  alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is change

`echo "<tr onclick="myFunction(this)" >`

to

`echo "<tr onclick=\"myFunction(".$i.")\">` or any other ID you expect inside it

You can easy test it with this:

```
<?php

for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
    echo "<button onclick=\"myFunction(".$x.")\">test it</button><br>";
} 

?>

<script>

function myFunction(x) {
    alert("Row index is: " + x);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ingus what i am doing here is summing a value for each selected row, and your answer helps with that, but now un-select  a row seems hard since there is no reference to which row is selected or not. any ideas (or should this be posted as a new question?)

Comment: @Manny I m glad that answer did help in some way! About your other question . .. Yeah i think that is a new one!

Answer (score -1):

onClick won't work this way for dynamically created elements.

You can use delegated event call using jQuery as:

```
$("table").on("click", "tr", function(){
    //Enter your code here
});
```